# SignalR and Database Communication Fails on StartUp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

In the website when a hub connection is established I call a server-side function to log the user information in the database. The table in the database is used to keep track of the user connected/disconnected status. I had noticed that not always the user shows up as connected. Thus I figure is because is was not writing to the table. I checked and there were no rows...

I added [ErrorHandlingPipeline](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server) to catch the error. All I got was `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. The function that appears to be producing the error is the first function I call when a connection is started as mentioned before. Here is:

```
public async Task Join()
{
   var user      = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
   var groupName = user.Group;

   await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
   Clients.Group(groupName).addUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);

   // Update group in the db
   using (var db = new UserEntities())
   {
      var connection = db.OnlineUsers.Find(Context.ConnectionId);
      connection.Group = groupName;
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

I also had placed a breakpoint in `public override Task OnConnected()` but it appears that `Join()` is called first? since it did not stop in that one.
I think that, that is the problem but why `OnConnected` will not be called first then?

Here is the hub:

```
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
       // connected
       theHub.server.join();
   });
```

**Update:**
Looks like the problem might be with IE11, it works on FireFox and Chrome. Here is the console log from IE:

```
SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:1234/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=1234%3connectionData=%a%b&tid=1'.
SignalR: Websocket opened.
SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
SignalR: Invoking MyHub.Join
SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addUser' on hub 'MyHub'.
SignalR: MyHub.Join failed to execute. Error: There was an error invoking Hub method 'MyHub.Join'.
SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addUser' on hub 'MyHub'.
[SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addUser' on hub 'MyHub'.
SignalR: Invoking MyHub.GetaddUser
```

Comment: whats your database instance that its trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

Your OnConnected will get called when you subscribe to a hub, without a subscription the OnConnected will not get fired first. It does not appear that you are subscribing to a hub.

This question may help

[OnConnected method not called SignalR when I use shared connection in multiple hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779150/onconnected-method-not-called-signalr-when-i-use-shared-connection-in-multiple-h)

Here is some sample code to connect and subscribe to a hub from your JQuery

The C# Hub

```
[HubName("YourHubName")]
public class YourHubName : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("Subscribe")]
    public void Subscribe(string groupId)
    {                       
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupId);

        Clients.Group(groupId).addMessageToPage("Sucessfully subscribed to group : " + groupId);
    }
}
```

And here is the JQuery

```
var connection = null;
var hub = null;

function initializeHub(signalRServer)
{
    connection = $.hubConnection(signalRServer);
    hub = connection.createHubProxy('YourHubName');
}

function subscribeToHub(groupId)
{
    try
    {
        connection.start(
        { 
            transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'], 
            withCredentials: false 
        })
        .done(function ()
        {
            hub.invoke('Subscribe',groupId)
                .done(function () {                
                    console.log("Subscribed");
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    console.log('Failed to subscribe');
                });
        })
        .fail(function (error)
        {
            console.log("An error occured with signarR connection : " + error);
        });   

        /*Declared the addMessageToPage method which SignalR will push to*/
        hub.on('addMessageToPage', function (message) {
            console.log("Message received from SignalR server : " + message);
        });         
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("An error occured with subscription process");
    }
}
```

Then, in the page calling the Hub

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initializeHub("YourSignalRUrlHere"]");
}
```

And when you want to trigger a subscription to a hub just call

```
subscribeToHub("HubGroupId");
```

Comment: I do subscribe to the hub before starting the connection, updated post to reflects this. It turns out that OnConnected is called first on Firefox and Chrome every single time. Why in IE 11 is not behaving? See updated post for IE11 console log.

Comment: This is strange, I will do a little research and post back

Comment: Wait a minute what will be the `signalRServer` when creating the proxy?

Comment: Refering to the `signalrRUrl` that is passed in to the initialize routine specifically. Is this related to: `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>` ?

Comment: The problem was using a generated proxy in the layout and in a view for a different connection. Thanks!